# Azure AD - Sign Up without B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-msal

I've been messing around with MSAL having previously used ADAL for sign up & secure API calls within AAD

I have a user case now requiring sign up and sign in but bafflingly MSAL - even tho there's a method for returning user name - is incapable currently of returning you anything about the user from the B2C token

The workaround seems horribly contrived so I'm considering abandoning MSAL and going back to ADAL or other providing the Sign Up or Sign in is also available

Can anyone recommend me a library or method of achieving Sign Up directly into AAD using ADAL or other please?

Answer (score 1):

> is incapable currently of returning you anything about the user from
>   the B2C token

[ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) supports for v1 endpoint.B2C uses v2 endpoint, and the [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries) is designed to support v2, so you could not use ADAL for the B2C Sign Up. If you want to get user information in the token, suggest you use the OpenId Connect. In the OpenId Connect, the id_token includes the user information.

You could use [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to parse the id_token, and you could find username in the id_token:

[image]

For the details about OpenId Connect in B2C, please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc).

Comment: Thank you. I did find a long winded way of doing what I want but it meant embedding a client secret in my app, amazingly that's the recommended way of doing it!

Comment: You are welcome. Later if there is anything update, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: @Journeyman1234 Are you adding the client_secret key to your app code to retrieve the bearer token?

Comment: @DeanB_Develop - yes, which just feels wrong. But it works. So what happens is my user authenticates using MSAL and retrieves a token. I then make a call to the AAD GraphAPI (which is where the secret comes in) to return me a user matching the unique ID of the token

Comment: Have you tried to use `this.authService.acquireTokenSilent(...)` ?  This returns a bearertoken than can be used by the API and doesn't require a client_secret.  Using a client-secret is good for `Get access without a user` or oAuth 2.0 auth code grant.  However, in this case, you're using a signed-in user and OpenID Connect (this.authService.acquireTokenSilent) will work. I hope.

Comment: @DeanB_Develop - I'm sorry, is there any chance you could show me what you mean with a C# example? To be absolutely clear, I am using MSAL to obtain a token, and silent to refresh that token. How am I supposed to use that token to get the bearer token that will work with graph?

Comment: @SunnySun-MSFT again many thanks for the link to OpenID connect but I failed so far to find a way to construct a URL to retrieve a suitable token that doesn't require the user to sign in again first - the documentation says such a request would require an authorisation code which is only obtained on sign in. Hope you can help .. .!

Answer (score 0):

ADAL and MSAL are incompatible

MSAL doesn't support Graph

OpenID Connect needs an authorisation code so isn't appropriate for the workflow

The answer I figured out was to install ADAL into my API, then when the user logs in on the app send securely the GUID from the token to the API which can then communicate with the Graph and return user profile info